# Subdomain for each manufacturer on Prestashop 1.5

Tags: prestashop

On Prestashop 1.5 I have a subdomain for each manufacturer.

I'm interested to display (for example) domainshop.com/?id_manufacturer=45 with the subdomain (for example) *manufacturerX.domainshop.com*

How can I do it? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you have few manufacturer, you can do it easily modifying .htaccess.

Add these lines for each manufacturer (replace "2" & "manufac" with the ID & the name of your manufacturer) :

```
# redirect to manufacturer subdomain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^manufacturerX.domainshop.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domainshop.com/2_manufacturerX [R=301,L,QSA]
```